# Noda Time - Start/end of day with zone

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, nodatime

What's the proper and more concise way to get the ZonedDateTime(s) which represent the start and the end of the current day in the timezone set on the system on which the code runs?

Isn't the following code too much complicated?

```
ZonedDateTime nowInZone = SystemClock.Instance.Now.InZone(DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl.GetSystemDefault());

ZonedDateTime start = new LocalDateTime(nowInZone.Year, nowInZone.Month, nowInZone.Day, 0, 0, 0).InZoneStrictly(DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl.GetSystemDefault());

ZonedDateTime end = new LocalDateTime(nowInZone.Year, nowInZone.Month, nowInZone.Day, 23, 59, 59).InZoneStrictly(DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl.GetSystemDefault());
```

Given those values, I need to test if another ZonedDateTime is between them.

Comment: You may want to use `InZoneLeniently` instead. For example, Brazil, on its forward DST transition, goes from 11:59pm to 1am. There is no 12:00 am. `InZoneStrictly` will throw in that case. `InZoneLeniently` would go to 1am when converting a LocalDateTime of 12am (if I'm reading the docs correctly). Similarly on the backwards transition it goes from 11:59pm to 11pm. There are two 11:59pm's. `InZoneLeniently` selects the later one.

Comment: @mikez - Good point about Brazil.  That is already covered by the method I demonstrated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `AtStartOfDay` value on the `DateTimeZone` object has the magic you're looking for.

```
// Get the current time
IClock systemClock = SystemClock.Instance;
Instant now = systemClock.Now;

// Get the local time zone, and the current date
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault();
LocalDate today = now.InZone(tz).Date;

// Get the start of the day, and the start of the next day as the end date
ZonedDateTime dayStart = tz.AtStartOfDay(today);
ZonedDateTime dayEnd = tz.AtStartOfDay(today.PlusDays(1));

// Compare instants using inclusive start and exclusive end
ZonedDateTime other = new ZonedDateTime(); // some other value
bool between = dayStart.ToInstant() <= other.ToInstant() &&
               dayEnd.ToInstant() > other.ToInstant();
```

A couple of points:

- It's better to get in the habit of separating the clock instance from the call to Now.  This makes it easier to replace the clock later when unit testing.
- You only need to get the local time zone once.  I prefer to use the `Tzdb` provider, but either provider will work for this purpose.
- For the end of day, it's better to use the start of the next day.  This prevents you from having to deal with granularity issues, such as whether you should take 23:59, 23:59:59, 23:59.999, 23:59:59.9999999, etc.   Also, it makes it easier to get whole-number results when doing math.

  In general, date+time ranges (or time-only ranges) should be treated as half-open intervals `[start,end)` - while date-only ranges should be treated as fully-closed intervals `[start,end]`.
- Because of this, the start is compared with `<=` but the end is compared with `>`.
- If you know for certain that the other `ZonedDateTime` value is in the same time zone and uses the same calendar, you can omit the calls to `ToInstant` and just compare them directly.

**Update**

As Jon mentioned in comments, the `Interval` type may be a useful convenience for this purpose.  It is already set up to work with a half-open range of `Instant` values.  The following function will get the interval for a the current "day" in a particular time zone:

```
public Interval GetTodaysInterval(IClock clock, DateTimeZone timeZone)
{
    LocalDate today = clock.Now.InZone(timeZone).Date;
    ZonedDateTime dayStart = timeZone.AtStartOfDay(today);
    ZonedDateTime dayEnd = timeZone.AtStartOfDay(today.PlusDays(1));
    return new Interval(dayStart.ToInstant(), dayEnd.ToInstant());
}
```

Call it like this (using the same values from above):

```
Interval day = GetTodaysInterval(systemClock, tz);
```

And now comparison can be done with the `Contains` function:

```
bool between = day.Contains(other.ToInstant());
```

Note that you still have to convert to an `Instant`, as the `Interval` type is not time zone aware.

Comment: It was well hidden in plain sight ;)
Thanks for the answer and for those best practices you pointed out.

Comment: You might also want to mention `Interval` - for example, you could easily write a method which returns an interval for "today" given a clock and a time zone (or a ZonedClock from 2.0...)

Comment: Wouldnt the updated example using Interval be incorrect as it includes the start of the next day?

Comment: @GlennMorton - It is a half-open interval.  In other words, the start is inclusive, but the end is excluded.  This a very useful concept when working with time.  The `Interval` type models it nicely.