# Noda time comparisons between zoned datetime and instant

Tags: nodatime

I am writing a function to test if a file creation time is before the start of the current day in a different time zone, and fetch if my local file copy is stale.

Checking here [Noda Time - Start/end of day with zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559333/noda-time-start-end-of-day-with-zone) I have come up with the below:

```
bool FileCreationIsBeforeStartOfDayInNewYork()
{
    var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
    var nowInNewYork = SystemClock.Instance.InZone(zone).GetCurrentZonedDateTime();
    var today = nowInNewYork.Date;
    var startOfDay = zone.AtStartOfDay(today);
    var fileCreationTime = ZonedDateTime.FromDateTimeOffset(File.GetLastWriteTime(Filename).ToUniversalTime());
    return fileCreationTime.ToInstant() < startOfDay.ToInstant();
}
```

The `File.GetLastWriteTime` method returns the file modification time of the local system clock.

I am confused if I should be converting the file creation time to the systems local time or if stick with UTC, and if my use of `ToInstant` is correct in this context?

Comment: Using Instant seems fine to me - although I'd just use `Instant.FromDateTime(File.GetLastWriteTime(Filename).ToUniversalTime())` to get the instant at which the file was last written. (There's no need to go via ZonedDateTime.)

Comment: (But it's not *really* clear to me what you're asking here...)

Comment: (Sorry, I meant `Instant.FromDateTimeUtc`, not `Instance.FromDateTime`.)

Comment: Thanks Jon. Makes sense with the Instant shortcut. The question is related to comparison of timezones, and use of UTC for this comparison, and moreover why `Instant` is used instead of a converting both the file time and the time to compare, to a `ZonedDateTime`. But i see Instant is essentially the same as UTC?

Comment: Well, Instant has *no* relationship to time zones. If time zones didn't exist, UTC wouldn't exist... but instants still would. Instants are just a timeline with no reference to any locations, whereas UTC is a sort of "international sea level" for time zones.