# Is there a function that gets end of day and time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

Is there a function like `EODAY(GETDATE())` that will return `2023-03-13 23:59:59` or do I have to handle that manually?

EDIT:

For clarification, this is to be used in a WHERE clause as a datetime value.

If I'm checking in a date range between 2023-03-10 and 2023-03-13, I want it to be checked against `2023-03-13 23:59:59` not `2023-03-13 00:00:00`.

But I'm seeing that a lot of people are suggesting doing `< 2023-03-14` for accuracy.

Comment: Almost always a bad idea to do this. An *exclusive* endpoint (`2023-03-14T00:00:00`) and appropriate comparison (`<` rather than `<=`) is a *lot* easier to get right, without having to know how many fractional seconds are relevant to your times. Your current end value, for example, would exclude anything that happens *during* the final second of the day.

Comment: One little approach is  format( getdate() , 'yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59')    Depending on datetime or datetime2(n)   you can add milliseconds.

Comment: Why do you want to get that value? This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) to me. As @Damien_The_Unbeliever states, if this is for some kind of date range you would be better off with the upper boundary being the moment *after* the boundary ends. Instead of `BETWEEN '2023-03-13T00:00:00.0000000' AND '2023-03-13T23:59:59.9999999'` just do `>= '20230313'` and `< '20230314'`.

Comment: `2023-03-13 23:59:59` isn't the end of day. The [actual term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00) refers to `24:00` in air/military/24-hour time and is considered different from `00:00` of the next day. I don't know of any database or programming language that can handle this. Use `< '20230314'` instead of trying to come up with infinite nines

Comment: What you want is 23:59:59.997 anyway (if we're talking datetime)

Comment: @On The Net Again Please update your title and your question to reflect why you want this. The context affects the correctness of each approach.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Why is everyone assuming that this is for inclusion in a where statement and maybe not on a display? I'm just curious.... Where does the user say he wants this for a where condition?

Comment: @Menelaos The OP wants the "end of day and time" and proposes the value might be `2023-03-13 23:59:59`. Unless the OP is using `datetime2(0)` (or a string of their own design) then that isn't the last time within a date. Whatever the ultimate use of the value might be, there is a substantial likelihood that: (1) the OP isn't aware of the problems that frequently occur in handling end-of-day and (b) that other users will cut'n'paste the answer without understanding the implications. A `where` _clause_ is just one possible, though common, use. Display formatting should be an application issue.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, in SQL Server, you do **NOT** use a `BETWEEN` operation to check date ranges. That is, if you have `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` `DateTime` values, and a column named `TimeStamp`, you should **NOT** write the `WHERE` predicate like this:

```
WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Instead, the better way to handle this is writing separate checks for the upper and lower bounds, where the lower bound check is *inclusive* and the upper bound checks is *exclusive* for the *day after*:

```
WHERE @StartDate <= TimeStamp AND TimeStamp < DATEADD(day, 1, @EndDate)
```

Comment: What does this even have to do with the question?

Comment: Everything. The OP asked if there's a function that returns EOD or they have to do it manually. The answer is they have to do it manually

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos *sigh* the answer is based on extra information in the comments. But not on the initial request. The question should be rewritten to be more specific. Eg without the specific comments - the question might have been how to serialize the EOD (1 second before midnight) to a text file (or something else).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Tell me where the user points out that the question is related to a `where` condition? It's the reason I ask the user for further context. The user asked for an output... Where in the question is a `where` condition mentioned? If you find it, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @Menelaos I made an **inference**. The primary reason to need an end of day value is for use as a _predicate_, of a which a `WHERE` clause condition is by far the most common.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I disagree. It's an inference when taking into account all similar questions on stackoverflow. It's a guess in isolation. There is nothing in the current OP information or question that allows inferring the need. It might be for a where... it might be for showing a timestamp to a user.

Comment: I would use caution with this approach. If someone were to declare an @EndDate and select GetDate() into it, you are going to wind up with erratic results when you use DATEADD and checking beneath it. I know what your intent is here, but it only woks out when you set an EndDate without a timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't one, for (at least) two good reasons:

1. Excluding leap seconds, the end of the day is always at the same time - it's never going to be anything other than `23:59:59.9999999[...]` - so there really is no need for a function when a constant can be used.
2. As Damien_The_Unbeliever wrote in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75723130/is-there-a-function-that-gets-end-of-day-and-time/75723281#comment133582901_75723130), even though that value is a constant, it does depend on the level of accuracy you're using - if you're measuring time in seconds, it's one thing, if you're using milliseconds it's another thing, and so on.

Comment: There's actually a business/military/air term `End Of Day` which refers to `24:00`. Even though computers can't tell the difference, End of Monday really is different than Start of Tuesday, especially when that refers to airport slots, arrival times, and whether your ticket gets charged extra because it's across dates. And yes, that's a thing. And flight departure and arrivals *are* published as `24:00`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, I wasn't aware of this. It's always good to learn new things, though I'm not sure this information is relevant to this question and answer.

Comment: When people ask for End Of Day this is what usually hides behind this. You can approximate it with `< '20230314'` but not `2023-03-13 23:59:59`, precisely due to leap second an inaccuracies in date calculations, especially with the `datetime` type

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the OP specifically asked for `23:59:59`, not for `24:00`... However, even if that's the case, there's still no built in function in SQL Server to return any date with the EndOfDay time (nor is it a valid time in SQL Server, for that matter). The best you can do is to use 00:00 of the next date - which is what damien wrote about in his comment. I've answered the question as asked, IMHO with a good answer. Your comment about the business term `End Of Day ` added some valuable knowledge but didn't contradict my answer.

Comment: I didn't say the answer was wrong, quite the opposite. There were a few discussions about this some years ago with Matt Jonhnon-Pint and Jon Skeet about possibly adding `AsEndOfDay` to NodaTime but it would be too messy. As MJP explains [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559333/noda-time-start-end-of-day-with-zone) `date+time ranges (or time-only ranges) should be treated as half-open intervals`. There's not much add to that answer